# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.examples.tutorials'

Tags: tensorflow, path, python-3.7

**I have pip installed my tensorflow cpu version.**

Name: tensorflow

Version: 2.0.0

Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.

Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/

Author: Google Inc.

Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org

License: Apache 2.0

Location: c:\users\kulothungan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages

Requires: opt-einsum, astor, keras-applications, google-pasta, keras-preprocessing, numpy, tensorflow-estimator, wrapt, grpcio, six, gast, protobuf, wheel, termcolor, tensorboard, absl-py

**Following is the code which I am trying to run**

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot = True)
```

**Following is the error which I get when I try to run my code:**

> RESTART:
>   C:\Users\Kulothungan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\asfd.py 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Kulothungan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\asfd.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.examples.tutorials'

**Following is the location of my code:**

C:\Users\Kulothungan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37

**I have already tried putting it in tuorial folder as other posts have mentioned.
Does anyone have any solution?**

Comment: The `tensorflow.examples.tutorials` the module is not included in the pip package. You will find it in TF's GitHub repo.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. Should I download it and place in my directory?

Comment: You can clone the repository and then open the examples directory.

Comment: Thanks. This solved my issue.Can you post this as solution so I can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tensorflow.examples.tutorials the module is not included in the pip package. You will find it in TF's GitHub repo.

Comment: did anyone find the repo?

Comment: and how to use it in colab?

Answer (score 0):

If you can `! git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git` the TF GitHub repo and in the downloaded folders locate where the `input_data.py` file is then copy and paste it in the working directory of your project then `import input_data` on your python terminal, it will sort it out for you.

It works even on colab.

you can watch this [beautiful video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CH8uW3abI9A&feature=youtu.be) that helps to explain it even better: